How do I parallelize code where each worker needs to operate in a separate folder?
I have some code (let's call it a function do_stuff(x)) which makes calls to an external executable using subprocess.run. That external executable needs to read and write local files with hardcoded names (I have no control over the way this was designed). Therefore, if I want to run more than one instance of that code at the same time, I need to actually copy that external executable and its related local files to a separate folder.
In the big picture I need to run do_stuff(x) with around 50 different values of x so I would like to parallelize the code that calls do_stuff so the batch run takes less time.
I have a handle on how to copy the files I need to a new folder (either something I specify explicitly or by using tempfile) and I have seen examples of various approaches to parallelization using multiprocessing, joblib, asyncio, etc. (for example here) but the catch is that because of the constraint imposed by my external executable, a given call needs to know what worker it is so it can operate in the right folder.
So if, for example, I want 4 workers and I create folders "temp1", "temp2", temp3", and "temp4", I need whatever parallelization approach is to use all four workers and all four temp folders such that only one thing is trying to run in each temp folder at a time. Unless I'm missing something obvious (which is certainly possible), it seems like I would need to have each call to do_stuff discover which worker it is so it can know what folder to work in. I think I might be able to do that by something like os.chdir(f'temp{multiprocessing.current_process()._identity[0]}') but that seems rather like a hack that's prone to breaking (e.g. if the parallelization approach is creating threads instead of processes).
I suppose I could have every single call to do_stuff make its own copy, execute, and clean up after itself, but that seems like a lot of wasteful file system operations which won't come for free either.
In case it's relevant to recommending an approach, the call to the external executable takes roughly 1 second but do_stuff typically calls that executable between 20 and 500 times as dictated by scipy.optimize.minimize.
